# Average by day SQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, datetime, average

I need to have a table with the average by hour or by day of a table.
The problem is the average is made by hour/min/sec

Here's the query:
[image]

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors-when-asking-a-question#:~:text=Images%20are%20harder%20to%20read,actual%20code%20and%20formatting%20it.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL you need to `CONVERT` the date

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DATE_PEREMPTION, 112) AS TIME_PERIOD, AVG(MESURE) AS MESURE
...
GROUP BY TIME_PERIOD
ORDER BY TIME_PERIOD
```

This might be a useful reference :
https://www.sqlservertutorial.net/sql-server-system-functions/convert-datetime-to-string/

Comment: I would suggest converting to a date instead of a string. It is almost always best to keep the datatype correct.

Answer (score 0):

I solved using this code.

```
SELECT cast(DATE_PEREMPTION as date) as DATE_PEREMPTION, ROUND(STDEV(MESURE),3) AS MESURE

FROM [MECMAS].[dbo].[T_Batch] B Join [MECMAS].[DBO].[TR_BATCH_MP] MP ON ([MP].ID_BATCH =B.ID )

Join [mecmas].[dbo].[T_DONNEES] d on (d.ID=MP.ID_DONNEES)

WHERE B.DATE_PEREMPTION >= '2022-01-01 00:00:00.00' AND NAME='AGUA' group by cast(DATE_PEREMPTION as date) ORDER BY DATE_PEREMPTION
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uirVW.png)

Comment: “While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.”

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).